# CMakeLists Equivalent of -B CL Argument

Tags: cmake

I am very new to CMake, so please excuse my ignorance. I've searched all over the available tutorials with no luck.

Is there an equivalent `set(...)` line I can use inside CMakeLists.txt that performs the same function as the `-B` command line argument (e.g. - `cmake -H. -Btest\build`)?

Comment: Because it makes a difference; what OS are you using [cmake](https://manpage.me/?q=cmake) on?

Comment: I'm learning on Windows 10, but would probably like to add in commands for each OS type since I have Ubuntu systems as well.

Comment: Well, I'm on UNIX. But if I understand your objective. Looking at the [man](https://manpage.me/?q=cmake) page seems to suggest using: `--build` as the `-B` equivalent, which also permits `--target` that may also help.

Comment: In other words you want to change **build directory** in the `CMakeLists.txt`. Several questions on this topic have already existed on Stack Overflow. I have choosen the one of them as a duplicate. The short answer would be: "No, you cannot do that".

Comment: That link is exactly what I was looking for, but since build directory is fairly generic, I could not find it. Thanks!